# Flutter http.post method doesn't work for me. Every time I try to run it, it brings up ticker.dart

Tags: flutter, http, flutter-bloc

```
Future<LoginResponse> authenticate(LoginRequest request) async {
  var url = _baseUrl + loginUrl;
  Map<String, String> headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json;'};
  final res = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: request.toJson());
  if (res.statusCode == 201) {
    Map<String, dynamic> response = jsonDecode(res.body);
    var json = LoginResponse(res.statusCode,
        response: response, token: response['user_access_token']['key']);
    return json;
  } else {
    Map<String, dynamic> response = jsonDecode(res.body);
    var json =
        LoginResponse(res.statusCode, response: response, error: res.body);
    return json;
  }
}
```

This is my code in UserRepository and I am using flutter_bloc to pass in the request model.

Below is the logic in the AuthBloc. I am pretty sure the issue is in the `http.post` method because when I remove the headers my request is processed but responds with an error.

```
Stream<AuthState> _mapLoginToState(String email, String password) async* {
  yield AuthenticationLoadingState();
  LoginRequest request =
      LoginRequest(email: email, password: password);
  var res = await userRepository.authenticate(request);
  if (res.code == 201) {
    var token = res.token;
    if (token != '' && token != null) {
      await userRepository.saveToken(token);
      yield AuthenticatedState();
    } else {
      await userRepository.deleteToken();
      yield UnAuthenticatedState();
    }
  } else {
    print(res.error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was I forgot to wrap `jsonEncode()` over body.

I fixed the problem and the code just works.